# Dynamically remove A LOT of <options> from <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

Does anyone have any solution to improve the speed when deleting/adding `<option>` from a `<select>` when it has 60k+ elements?

I've a form with two `<select>`, let's call them `selectA` and `selectB`. I want the values of `selectB` to change when `selectA` is changed. Like (code not functional, just for idea):

```
if selectA = option1
    then selectB.options = [opt1_1, opt1_2, opt1_3, ...]
else if selectA = option2
    then selectB.options = [opt2_1, opt2_2, opt2_3, ...]
...
```

I have a (quite huge) variable that gives me the list of option for selectB associated with selectA value.
I've found many example for that kind of thing and it works on small examples. For now, I've something like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectB").html("<option value='' slected='selected'>Choose SelectA first</option>");
    $("#selectA").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        var options = //... string generated with all <option></options> depending on $val
        $("#selectB").html(options)
    });
});
```

Here comes the mess, as `selectB` is a list of IPv4 that can contain a full /16. So that's 60k+ elements to handle (ouch ^^ ). And that's why I don't want to have every option in the select but instead "pre-select" with selectA and then "sub-select" with selectB.

I want to have all possible IPs initially in the HTML form because of the following reason : Even if JS is not enabled, the user must be able to choose one IP (the server checks that the choice from selectA and selectB corresponds). And only if JS is enabled I remove everything from selectB and add only the values I want when selectA is changed. So you might say that anyway a user with no JS can't event choose an option without loading 1GB+ RAM of options and wait 5-10 min for every option to be loaded, but I also want the page to works if there is only a few options to display like 1k.

I've to admit I was amazed my browser (FF) handles the creation of the page quite quickly. But when JS delete all the options, everything freezes on :

```
$("#selectB").html("<option value='' slected='selected'>Choose SelectA first</option>");
```

What I've managed to debug is that what takes time is when the browser needs to unload/delete every options. Actually creating them is not that slow.

So I would like to know if there is a faster solution than what I'm doing right now. How can I speed up the deletion of all `<option>` in selectB ?

Any suggestion is welcome from a simple change in JS to change the whole structure of HTML to not use `<select>` but something else (I don't know).

Comment: Any attempts you make to speed this up will be relatively moot, as you shouldn't be dumping 60,000 options in to the DOM in the first place. It's completely unworkable for your users to deal with that much information. I'd strongly suggest you look in to a filtering solution, such as Select2. This will both improve UX as only relevant information will be shown to the user based on their input, and (providing you use AJAX to filter the data server side) it'll speed up your page as you're not dumping Mbs worth of text in to the DOM.

Comment: That said, you state that the options are IP addresses, hence would it not make more sense to use 4 separate text inputs (restricted to digits) to allow direct entry?

Comment: 60K is phenomenal, as @RoryMcCrossan has suggested, you WILL have to deploy a filtering based process. I suggest looking into twitters typeahead: https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/